# Search row for defined text and if present, copy and paste it in same row and empty column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have delimited text of contact information all separated into different cells from a text import of a PDF document.  It's 800 pages and all I want are the lines that contain data from certain states.  ie. `FL`, `VA` & `NC`.  I want each line to be searched and if any of these three values are present, then in column A, same line, copy and paste it there so I can sort only these three States' contact information to the top for editing.

*Transfer clarification provided in comment:*

> Including the empty column A I've created to paste the state into, the data range is from B to P. The state codes will be guaranteed to be in their own cell but not in the same column. I can do one state at a time so the first formula written in A1 I need would ask it to search all cells to the right and if a cell contains FL then tell me here in cell A1 somehow.. Then I copy that formula all the way down column A pulling out all the lines that pertain to that state

and *Change in requirement*

> Ok... need the formula to do one more thing. Right now, if it reads the text, FL, to the right, it puts a number in column A corresponding to how many cells over it is. ie. If the FL is in column C it puts a 2 in Column A same row. If it's in column E, it puts a 4. So the sorting issue I have now is that the name of the contact and it's street address is in the line immediately before the line with the state and I need that line identified for sorting purposes as well. So the line with the address and the one with the state would have to have a unique value so they would sort together.

Comment: So `FL`,`VA`, or `NC` might possibly be in different cells?

Comment: Including the empty column A I've created to paste the state into, the data range is from B to P.  The state codes will be guaranteed to be in their own cell but not in the same column.  I can do one state at a time so the first formula written in A1 I need would ask it to search all cells to the right and if a cell contains FL then tell me here in cell A1 somehow.. Then I copy that formula all the way down column A pulling out all the lines that pertain to that state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use something like that (I broke it down to several lines since otherwise it's quite long):

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B1:P1,1,
  IFERROR(MATCH("VA",B1:P1,0),0)+
  IFERROR(MATCH("NC",B1:P1,0),0)+
  IFERROR(MATCH("FL",B1:P1,0),0)
 )&":"&ROW(),IF(A2=A3,"N/A",A2))
```

[This function starts on row 1. Change the ranges to `B2:P2` if your data starts on row 2, and `A2` to `A3`]

The result of this function would be `SS:N` where `SS` represents the state and `N` represents a unique ID, which will correspond to the row number the state was found in. I'm assuming that rows alternate between name and address, and then the line with the state information.

Upon sorting, you'll have all the lines sorted first by state, then by the unique number.

Comment: #N/A M19786-P19786 Prima Sausage Co 3098 76th ave
3 Processing Medley FL 33166

Comment: #N/A M19786-P19786 Prima Sausage Co Inc 77  76th ave
3 Processing Medley FL 33166

Comment: Sorry, trying to show you how the first formula looks. FL only. Row 1 has the company name and address then row 2 starts with a 3(saying how many cells over the FL appears) then the words processing medley FL 33166.  I need the FL only formula to put unique sorting text in A1(address and contact line) and then simply FL in A2 (pulling out the city and state row)  Sorry if this is getting confusing.  The big formula you sent didn't work.  I hope doing just 1 state simplifies it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually, correction... I think the 2 cells(A1&A2) need to be equal and unique to any other 2 row combinations of contact address(row 1) and city state(row 2)

Comment: So the bottom line is if a Cell on a row is detected with an FL in it, assign it a value, put in A2 and then assign the row directly above it(A1) the same value so I can pull out each combo of rows that pertain to the street address(row 1) and city/state(row2) out of 28,000 rows of information. Thanks

Comment: @user3228329 I'm not sure exactly how that is not working, or maybe I misunderstood something. Try to download and see [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23298677/SO%2021311962.xlsx)?

Comment: Thank you.  That's it!  I copied your formula from the file and it worked.  Thanks so much.

Comment: The formula is also pulling over all other non target state info too.(using the same unique identifiers in column A)  Example, in the file you sent me, I inserted one additional contact address(two rows) using street address(row 1) and the state OH (row 2) Moving the sample file up to 11 rows of data.  The formula then produces the following in Column A, rows 6,7,9 & 9: "NC:9" Forcing me to have to manually select and delete rows 6 & 7(the non target OH address)Can we add a qualifier that tells it to ignore any entries into column A unless its the target states? can u send a new file w the fix

Comment: @user3228329 I updated the link to the excel above.

Comment: Thanks Jerry.  Got one more if you're not too tired of me... I've sorted and edited the sheet to just target state data now.  The final step I need to do is sort the final good data by zip code for mapping software.  I've created a new column A on this new edited sheet you've helped me with(by copying old column A and pasting, values only, then sorting) Now I want to add one more column A and have it search each row for a 5 digit zip code, ie. 23112, and if it finds a cell with 5 digits, copy it and put in new column A on the same row.  Can you update your file again? zips are in diff columns

Comment: @user3228329 That one's not gonna be easy with excel's default tools. Are there more numbers than the zip numbers? If no, maybe you could use this formula? `=INDEX(B3:P3,1,MATCH(1,(LEN(B3:P3)=5)*(ISNUMBER(B3:P3)),0))` (This is for row 3 and you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter for that to work as expected). I'll be gone for bed now and won't be able to reply for a while...

Comment: It's coming up with #VALUE! in all the cells.  Not sure what you mean by ctrl+shift+enter for that to work.  Thanks for your help.  I'll let you sleep.  My day's about over here too.  If you can get something to work on that file, I'll check for an update later.  Thank you so much! Oh... and the rows with the zips have no other numbers.  Just text data.

Comment: @user3228329 Okay, that might mean that the data is stored as text. Try `=INDEX(B3:P3,1,MATCH(1,(LEN(B3:P3)=5)*(ISNUMBER(B3:P3*1)),0))` instead (I added `*1` to convert text to number). When you enter a formula in a cell, you usually push the Enter key (or Return) to tell Excel the formula is done and to calculate, right? Instead, here, you need to push down and hold Control, Shift and then Enter (all three buttons should be pressed).

Answer (score 1):

For one State at a time something like `=MATCH("FL",B1:P1,0)` should serve, copied down to suit.

To deal with all three States at once I suggest:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("FL",B2:P2,0)),0,1)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("VA",B2:P2,0)),0,3)+IF(ISERROR(MATCH("NC",B2:P2,0)),0,5)
```

with the values representing the possible combinations.

Comment: +1: Formula is way better for this. @user3228329: Kindly accept his answer if you find it helpful by marking the answer as accepted (clicking on the check icon on the upper left hand side). This is how we say thanks in SO.

Comment: Ok... need the formula to do one more thing.  Right now, if it reads the text, FL, to the right, it puts a number in column A corresponding to how many cells over it is.  ie.  If the FL is in column C it puts a 2 in Column A same row.  If it's in column E, it puts a 4.  So the sorting issue I have now is that the name of the contact and it's street address is in the line immediately before the line with the state and I need that line identified for sorting purposes as well.  So the line with the address and the one with the state would have to have a unique value so they would sort together.